# Stop grid column from being trimmed (Ext JS)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid with 3 columns: title, content and date created. My largest column with most content is the `content` column. However this column can hold much more text than one row of the grid. Ext JS automatically trims the text from a certain point on.

Can I stop it from automatically trimming the values in the rows and just show the whole content? I would post my code, but it's an entire MVC pattern, which spreads over several files and it would take a lot of time to gather it all.

Comment: Can you upload the code to google code via svn and point us to the web page? also then your code would have the added advantage of being backed up.

Comment: +1 for this. as for my case, i have handled this by adding a renderer to my column `return '<div style="white-space:pre !important;">'+ val +'</div>';` since our server has returned a data with spaces/horizontal tabs on it like `Date[___________horizontal_tabs___________]Thu Jul 4 2013`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Preview or RowExpander plugin

- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.RowExpander
- http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.ux.PreviewPlugin

Here is the sample page you might want to look at:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/grid/paging.html

Basically idea is to have custom template which will render whole your data instead of having rows of the same height.